# Getting first line argument in bash after forking processes

Tags: bash

Here is my file.sh bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$(awk '/[ \t]+'$1'\/'$2'/' /etc/servicies) | awk '{print '$1'}';
```

if I run:

```
file.sh 21 tcp
```

it should print ftp. But I get that error:

```
./file.sh: line 2: ftp: command not found
```

Can anybody explain me a little bit why that error and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '/[ \t]+'$1'\/'$2'/ { print $1 }' /etc/services
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `$( ... )` construct? It is replaced by the output of the enclosed commands by bash, so your pipeline becomes something like

```
ftp   21/tcp   xxx_master    # ftp / XXX
```

which triggers the mentioned error.

Solution: Just remove the `$(` and `)` and everything should work as you expected.

Comment: It is not working. It prints me 21. the first argument that I pass when execute script. I need to take fist argument from printed line.

Comment: @artaxerxe: If you do not want the shell to interpret `$1`, do not use it unquoted: `awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
awk '$2==A && $3=B, NF=1' FPAT='[^ /]+' A=$1 B=$2 /etc/services
```

Comment: I don't understand what your command mean... I'm a newbie to awk

Answer (score 0):

kinda hard to understand but...
$(whatever) executes its output...
So, assuming that

```
$(awk '/[ \t]+'$1'\/'$2'/' /etc/services)
```

the part inside the $() gets you as output

```
ftp blahblahblah
```

it will first try to execute it and only after pass the execution output to the second awk piping.

Just remove the $() syntax, in that way the output of the first awk will be sent to the later steps.

Btw, please, instead of doing

```
cat xxxx | dosomething
```

try doing

```
dosomething xxxxx
```